# Link org-mode to external file with "[" or "]" in the path

Tags: org-mode, org-link, filenames

I have a "file name.txt" file whose full path is "G:/path1/[TAG] path2/file name.txt"

How do I write the link to the external file "file name.txt" in org-mode?

If I use [[file:G:/path1/[TAG] path2/file name.txt][link]] it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [section 4.1 of the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-Format.html), you'd need to escape paths with square brackets. Try

```
[[file:G:/path1/\[TAG\] path2/file name.txt][link]]
```

To make link creation/editing easier, look into `M-x org-insert-link` (bound to `C-c C-l` by default.